# jQuery Ajax - adding new Elements to DOM

Tags: ajax, dom, jquery

i try to figure out, how i can manage my dynamically loaded list to function with tooltips.
When a link has a title tag i want the tooltip function to start.
But i need to add the new Elements to the DOM so the function "sees" the title element.

This is how it looks right now:
Tooltip works but not with the loaded elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#home").click(function(){
        $(".content ").load("start.html");
    });
    $("[title]").style_my_tooltips({ 
        tip_follows_cursor: "on",
        tip_delay_time: 300 
    });
```

I tried it with bind and live but nothing worked for me.
My try with the live() function:

```
$("#home").live("click", function(){
    $(".content ").load("start.html");          
});
```

Didn't work.

Help appreciated.

greets Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run the plugin again on the new content, like this:

```
$("#home").click(function(){
  $(".content").load("start.html", function() {
    $("[title]", this).style_my_tooltips({ 
      tip_follows_cursor: "on",
      tip_delay_time: 300 
    });
  });
});
```

By using `this` as the context in `$("[title]", this)`, we're only looking for new `[title]` elements within that `.content` element you just loaded.